# Exim failing to send mail to emails within local_domains list

Tags: linux, exim, email-server

Cannot send mail using the command

```
    exim4 -bm undelivered@mydomain.com
```

Looking at the logs after this I see that R=dkimproxy and T=dkimproxy_smtp H=localhost[127.0.0.1]:10027.

I have seen the error in the logs saying **Unknown User**

It generates a bounceback which also uses the same router and transport and also fails, inevitably becoming frozen in the queue.

If I telnet to the server and send a mail from justin@mydomain.com account to this same undelivered@mydomain.com email address then the R=send_to_xcalibre T=remote_smtp H=(our MX records).

I don't know how to get the local mail to take the same path as the mail generated using telnet.

This exim setup was done by a previous employee and unfortunately the knowledge of how this all worked left with him.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is the routers section of exim4.conf

send_to_xcalibre:
  
driver = manualroute
  
domains = mydomain.com : myOtherDomain.com
  
condition = "${if eq {$interface_port}{25} {1}{0}}"
  
transport = remote_smtp
  
route_list = * primary-mail.mailhoster.co.uk

dkimproxy:
 
driver = manualroute
 
condition = "${if eq {$interface_port}{10025} {0}{1}}"
 
transport = dkimproxy_smtp
 
route_list = "* localhost byname"
 
self = send

Transports configuration

dkimproxy_smtp:
 
driver = smtp
 
port = 10027
 
allow_localhost

remote_smtp:
 
driver = smtp
 
headers_remove = X-Spam-Report:X-Spam-Bar:received

Comment: Add the following to your post: 1) the contents of the dkimproxy router 2) the contents of the dkimproxy_smtp transport.  My first hunch is that a restart of the dkimproxy application running on that machine will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had something to do with the way the DKIMproxy package works, it loops the message through the server, first time adding the DKIM signature and then second time sending it through to the destination.

However on the second loop the host changes and becomes localhost and uses the dnslookup router.

If the email originates from localhost then Exim tries to use dnslookup router immediately and this seems to fail.

I have decided to avoid the problem by redirecting these messages to another domain, so it is not recognised as localhost.

I realise not the best answer, just wanted to give anyone some more information if they found themselves here.